# How to center two frames in one window using tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, window, frame, center

All I want to do is center the top frame in this window, and it seems like it should be painfully simple, but after a week I still can't figure it out.

I have tried changing this from pack to grid. I've tried using expand, fill, sticky, and side. None of them work in any of their iterations or combinations.

What is happening here that is causing it to stick to the left of the screen and how can I just center it?

[Here is an image of the tkinter GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2PoB.png)

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

frame1 = tk.Frame(root, bg='gold')
frame2 = tk.Frame(root)

frame1label = tk.Label(frame1, bg='gold', text='Top label')
frame1label.grid(row=0)

frame2label = tk.Label(frame2, text='Bottom label')
frame2label.pack()

frame1.pack(fill=tk.X)
frame2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The top frame actually fills the width of the window.  It is just the label being put in the left because `grid(row=0)` is used.  Change `grid(...)` to `pack()`.

Comment: @acw1668 Yea that works but I need a way to center it while still using grid on that first label

Comment: Then add `frame1.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to tell widgets to expand if the grid resizes. You can do that with `columnconfigure`. Using the `sticky` parameter you can tell the widget *how* to react. Have a look at **Handling Resize** at this site: https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

frame1 = tk.Frame(root, bg='gold')
frame1.pack(fill=tk.X)
frame1.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame2 = tk.Frame(root)
frame2.pack()

frame1label1 = tk.Label(frame1, bg='gold', text='Top label')
frame1label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
frame2label = tk.Label(frame2, text='Bottom label')
frame2label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```